Apachi Nifi calling localhost insted of proxy server
I'm trying to host a standalone instance of NiFi Server on a VM.
I've followed all the basic instructions to set it up and configured an Nginx reverse proxy to make it easily accessible, but I just can't get it to work properly. Every time I change or move an object, it shows that NiFi isn't functioning correctly.
By checking the developer tools, I discovered that NiFi is attempting to connect to localhost instead of using my proxy server.
NIFI Screen
NIFI localhost api call
Even after setting proxy.host, it still trying to call on localhost.
nifi.properties
nifi.web.https.host=localhost
nifi.web.https.port=8443
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.application.protocols=h2 http/1.1
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=/
nifi.web.proxy.host=dashboard.cardsinova.local
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.max.access.token.requests.per.second=25
nifi.web.request.timeout=60 secs
nifi.web.request.ip.whitelist=
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true
nifi.web.request.log.format=%{client}a - %u %t "%r" %s %O "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"


Hi, did you see the guidance for the proxy configuration? https://nifi.apache.org/documentation/nifi-2.0.0-M3/html/administration-guide.html#proxy_configuration

No, I didnt. Its working now. Thx
